# Conversion to Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Please refer the below link

Please visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions

I am trying to convert the same application to Angular 6

But not been able to do so.

1) The HTML part i copied in test.component.html
2) the javascript part am trying to convert to typescript. This is where am not good.

Sorry i could not paste the code here since its all messed up with errors.

Suggest how to do or any ideas to convert the code, the place where am stuck is creation of events.

Regards,
Amit

Same code to be in angular 6

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript accepts Javascript, that means you can rename it to .ts, it would still work well.

After that, you can add type feature and arrow function to it, and update the var to const or let as well (basically this is ECMA feature, not Typescript)